# Why won't iCal delete meetings when I'm sent a cancellation notice?

Tags: ical

I'm on Lion. I have a client who sends meeting invites from her Outlook account (I think also Exchange server).  If I click on the .ics attachment it goes into iCal and I can accept/decline/maybe.  If she sends a notice of a cancellation I can't do anything to it. I have to go into iCal and manually delete the meeting (of course this is doable) but if it's a recurring meeting, it's not a delete but rather a decline.

Is there something I can do to fix this?
Maybe she's doign something weird on her side? (Totally possible.)